# C program gives incorrect output?

Tags: c

I am writing a C program which calculates average grade and tells if you pass or fail. The user can choose as many attempts as they want and they will be given a final average of all attempts. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    double num2, num3, average, average_1;

    printf("Enter number of attempts: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    while (num1 > 0) {
        printf("Enter your mark for subject one: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num2);

        printf("Enter your mark for subject two: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num3);

        if (num2 < 50 || num3 < 50) {
            printf("You have failed \n");
        } else {
            printf("You have passed \n");
        }

        num1--;
    }

    average = num1 * num2 * num3;
    average_1 = average / 100;

    printf("Average for all %d attempts is %.2f \n", num1, average_1);
}
```

The problem with this code is that the final output, which is the last printf line, gives me 0 for attempts and 0 for average. Here is the exact output:

```
Enter number of attempts: 2
Enter your mark for subject one: 49
Enter your mark for subject two: 96
You have failed
Enter your mark for subject one: 22
Enter your mark for subject two: 100
You have failed
Average for all 0 attempts is 0.00
```

Comment: I think you need to read a little more about average, because that's not what you're calculating.

Comment: The average is generally the sum of a set, divided by the number in the set. So your average calculation aught to be `average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3`

Comment: That's an interesting notion of average... anyway, you write `while (num1 > 0) { ... num1--; }` What do you expect num1 to be after that?

Comment: Yet another problem that could have been spotted, and easily fixed, with the most trivial debugging attempts. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dicrementing the variable num1. So, when you finish your loop you will have num1 = 0.

I suggest you do a 'for' instead of a 'while'. Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int num1, i;
double num2,num3,average,average_1;

printf("Enter number of attempts: ");
scanf("%d", &num1);

for(i = num1; i > 0; i--) {

        printf("Enter your mark for subject one: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num2);

        printf("Enter your mark for subject two: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num3);

        if (num2 < 50 || num3 < 50) {

                printf("You have failed \n");
        }
        else {
                printf("You have passed \n");
        }
}

average = num1*num2*num3;
average_1 = average / 100;
printf("Average for all %d attempts is %.2f \n", num1, average_1);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for correction. Can you tell me why while loop did not work in this case, but for loop worked. I am actually learning C programming on my own without any teacher because I work full-time as a System Admin, but I want to add new skills to my career. Thanks!

Comment: Well the while loop works this way: "While this condition is true, I'll continue to do this loop". So if you have a decrement at the end of the loop and your condition is to stop when it is not greater than 0, at the very last loop stage it will decrement "num1" to 0 and it'll get off the while statement. Your variable will have the 0 value, instead of the initial one. The ''for'' loop works because I'm using a different variable to change it's value. The famous "i". So "num1" continues to have the same value in the beginning of the code.

Comment: Your while loop could work if you decremented an auxiliary variable!! I suggest you practice programming with a lot of exercises. Search for Online Judges, they will hand you all kinds of easy to difficult problems and you will probably understand more about the particular cases of an specific language. Keep it up and don't give up!!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will iterate until `num1` is greater than `0` . As it decrement and become `0` program come out of loop  but `num1` has value `0` . Thus ,in these expressions `num1` is `0`-

```
average = num1*num2*num3;    // 0*num2*num3 therefore , 0
average_1 = average / 100;    // as average is 0 , thus result is 0
```

Also formula for calculating `average_1` is wrong . It should be -

```
average_1=average/3;    // you calculate average of 3 numbers
```

To get correct output create a temporary variable -

```
int i=num1;
while(i>0){
 // your code 
 i--;
}
```

In this way `num1` remain unchanged.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I should at least get the number of attempts that was entered because it was entered before the loop.

Comment: @Batool Original value is decrementated , you see . Print value of `num1` in loop and see the values yourself .

Answer (score 0):

You have put the average calculation part in wrong place. Once you're out of the `while` loop, `num1` will have a value `0`, hence all the related calculations will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are reducing `num1` until it becomes 0

```
while (num1 > 0) {
    // other code
    num1--;
}
```

Then naturally

```
 average = num1*num2*num3;
```

becomes

```
average = 0*num2*num3;
```

and that is 0

Answer (score 0):

First, because you deduct num1 by one till 0.

You should use for loop:

```
for(int counter = num1; num1 > 0; num--)
```

`{ Your code here }`

Answer (score 0):

after the while loop, your num1 will be 0.